# D3. How do I align an svg text string with an svg rect in a table row?

Tags: d3.js, svg

In D3 I have a simple table built with svg:

[image]

Each row consists of a rect followed by three (3) text string elements. I have had to resort to eye-balling the rect to line up with the text strings which is not ideal. Here is the markup:

[image]

Is there anyway to get height/width metric from the text to use to position the rect?

Comment: Yes, you can use `.getBBox()` on the DOM element.

Comment: So, since everything is configured dynamically, I set up my text, grab the bbox then use the bbox to position/size my rect?

Comment: Yep, that's the idea. The bbox will tell you the dimensions of the text, from which you can derive the position of the rect.

Comment: Cool. Thanks alot. Cheers.